# Wrong parameters with in controller (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three model associated with each other, User - Band - Advertisement

I'm a user, I am creating a band and then I would create an advertisement to recruit singer (for example)

In the list of the current user's bands, on every band name, I have a link to show that band's info.

In the show info page, I have a button to create an advertisement (this advertisement must belong to that band) so when I call the create method of Advertisement controller, I must pass also the band id.

So, in this view:

```
<%= button_to "New Advertisment", advertisment_new_path(:band_id => @band.id), :class => "btn btn-primary btn-md", :method => "get" %>
```

(The @band variable is correctly set in the code above, I used it for the show method of the Band controller and it works fine.)

In the 'new' of the controller Advertisement, I'm trying to catch this parameter, without success.

Controller:

```
def new
    @band= params[:band_id]
    some other code...
end
```

@band is nil.... any suggestions?

Comment: How's your show method defined?

Comment: What's in `rails routes`?

Comment: 'def show

  if(!params[:id].nil?)
   @band= Band.find(params[:id]) 
  else
   redirect_to "/404"
  end
 end'

Comment: get 'advertisment/index'

  get 'advertisment/show'
  
  get 'advertisment/new'

  post 'advertisment/create'

Comment: check what params you are getting in your controller method..

Comment: Please post your params as well.